# async class library dll method from asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm wanting to create a class library which can be called from my asp.net web page.
The library does a bunch of long running file ops.
How should this lib be built to enable the webpage to call the library and move on, ie not wait for a result or the call to finish? TIA

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET for .NET Framework, or ASP.NET Core? If so, what **exact version**?

Comment: In ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core), use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8 - in ASP.NET Core use `IHostedService`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice

Comment: ASP.NET nor ASP.NET Core impose any design requirements on your library - though note that ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core) makes it more difficult to work with `async` APIs (though not impossible), while ASP.NET Core works best with `async` APIs. Note that if you're using `FileStream` then there are hoops you need to jump-through to get async IO working properly.

Comment: Thanks for that. The website uses asp.net on .net 4.6. So I wrote my class lib in the same. Functionally works fine, just the page waits for the lib operation to complete. I'll research HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem Thank you people!